# Cannot read property 'value' of null in contrast checker

Tags: javascript, error-handling, properties, null, contrast

The only thing that I changed in my code was that I changed the IDs  e.g. previewContrast to preview_contrast and I get a Property value null error.
The error shows for the line "var color = colorObjekt.value.replace("#", "");

I would be grateful if someone could find the error in this code.

```
var textColorContrast = getColor('txtColor');
var bgColorContrast = getColor('bgColor');

var lumi1 = getLumi(textColorContrast);
var lumi2 = getLumi(bgColorContrast);

if (lumi1 !== false && lumi2 !== false) {
    txtColor.style.color = '#'+textColorContrast;
    bgColor.style.backgroundColor = '#'+bgColorContrast;
    var ratio = (Math.max(lumi1, lumi2) + 0.05) / (Math.min(lumi1, lumi2) + 0.05);
    contrastText.innerHTML = (Math.round(ratio * 100) / 100) + ':1';
}

function getColor(location) {
    var colorObjekt = document.getElementById(location);
    var color = colorObjekt.value.replace("#", "");
    return color;
}`
```

Here is the html

`<div class="tab-content container-fluid" id="navi_content" role="main">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="post" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="post-tab">
        <div class="row" role="row">
          <h2 role="heading" class="col-10">Input</h2>
          <div class="col-2" role="gridcell">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary fas fa-info" role="button"
              data-toggle="popover" title="Info" data-trigger="focus"
              data-content="On this page you can enter a text to display on the LED Scroll Board. You can also change the background and text color as well as the speed and brightness settings in the Settings modal. By selecting the Date or Clock Mode you can post the current date or time on to the board"
              data-placement="bottom"></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary fas fa-cogs" role="button" data-toggle="modal"
              title="Settings" data-target="#settings"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form class="text__form" id="form">
          <div class="form-row" role="row">
            <div class="form-group col-10" role="gridcell">
              <label class="text__label" for="text__input" id="input_label">
                Your message:
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control text__input-text" id="text_input"
                placeholder="Text input here... :)" role="textbox" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="input_abel" required>
              <p class="text__counter">150 characters left...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 text__colorpicker" role="gridcell">
              <div class="form-group" role="gridcell">
                <label class="text__label" for="text_color" id="text_color_label">Text Color</label>
                <input class="text__input-color" type="color" name="textcolor" id="text_color" value="#ff0000"
                  aria-labelledby="text_color_label">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card" role="none">
            <div class="card-body" role="group">
              <h3 class="card-header" role="heading">Modes</h3>
              <fieldset class="form-check" id="color_radios">
                <legend class="col-form-label text__card-label" id="modes_legend">
                  Color Modes
                </legend>
                <div class="row" role="row">
                  <div class="form-check form-group col-sm-6" role="form">
                    <input class="form-check-input text__input-radio" type="radio" name="colorMode"
                      id="rainbow_mode" value="1" role="radio" aria-labelledby="rainbow_label">
                    <label for="rainbow_mode" class="form-check-label text__card-label" id="rainbow_label">Rainbow
                      Mode</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check form-group col-sm-6" role="form">
                    <input class="form-check-input text__input-radio" type="radio" name="colorMode" id="solid_mode"
                      value="0" role="radio" aria-labelledby="solid_mode_label" aria-checked="true" checked>
                    <label for="solid_mode" class="form-check-label text__card-label" id="solid_mode_label">Solid
                      Mode</label>
                    <div class="form-group" role="form">
                      <label for="bg_color" id="bg_color_label" aria-label="Background Color"> Color</label>
                      <input type="color" name="bgColor" id="bg_color" value="#ABCDEF" aria-labelledby="bg_color_label">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>`

Comment: The error is saying that `colorObjekt` is `null` which means your `getElementById` is not picking up the correct element. Recheck your ids.

Comment: Also, its 'Object' not 'Objekt' .. :)